# How to calculate maximal parallelism in a DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a DAG (directed acyclic graph), how does one calculate the maximal parallelism?

Instantaneous parallelism is the maximum number of processors that can be kept busy at each point in execution of algorithm; the **maximal parallelism** is the highest instantaneous parallelism.

Put another way, given a DAG representing a dependency graph of tasks, what is the minimum number of processors/threads such that no task is ever blocked?

The closest approach I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790682/finding-the-width-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph-with-only-the-ability-to-find-p) is:

- apply a topological sort on the DAG
- traverse over the nodes by the topological order, calculate the minimum level:

  - no parents: 0
  - otherwise: minimum parent level + 1
- return the max level width (max num of nodes assigned the same level)

This algorithm worked for me on several samples, however doesn't work on a tree. E.g.:

```
  o 0
 / \
o 1 o 1
   / \
  o 2 o 2
     / \
    o 3 o 3
```

According to the algorithm above, max width is 2, but clearly  max parallelism in a tree is the number of leafs, 4 in the example above.

A similar approach is partially described [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS378/2015sp/lectures/Algorithm%20abstractions.pdf) (see slide titled `Computing critical path etc.`, which describes how to calculate earliest start times of nodes and that "maximal...parallelism can easily be computed from this").

---

Edit 1:

@AliSoltani's solution to use BFS to find the length of the critical path and that is the max parallelism degree is incorrect, since it only applies to a subset of examples, mainly trees in which the number of leafs is equal to the longest path. Here's an illustration of a case where this wouldn't work:

[image]

---

Edit 2:

@AliSultani's 2nd solution using BFS to find the level with maximum number of nodes, and set that max as the max parallelism, is also incorrect, as it doesn't take into account cases where nodes from different levels may run concurrently. See this counterexample:

[image]

Comment: Your examples are contradictory. In tree 1, you found `critical path length` (4) but in tree 2, you found `maximum degree of concurrency` (6). Please see page 7 in [this](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~nedialk/COURSES/4f03/Lectures/algdesign.pdf)

Comment: My solution find `critical path length` in all `Task-dependency graph`.

Comment: What is your issue? `critical path length` or `maximum degree of concurrency`?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is `maximum degree of concurrency`

Comment: I added find `maximum degree of concurrency` by BFS to my answer. Please see this again.

Comment: @AliSoltani sorry, wrong again; see counterexample in Edit 2 showing your max level approach is also incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is reducible to the [Maximum Directed Cut](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~mlampis/slides/ISAAC2009.pdf) problem.

Let's build an auxiliary DAG from the original one.

1. For every vertex `u[i]` of the original graph add vertexes `v[i]` and `w[i]` to the new graph, and connect them using an edge `(v[i], w[i])` with a cost `1`.
2. For every edge `(u[i], u[j])` of the original graph add an edge `(w[i], v[j])` with a cost `0` to the new graph.
3. Now the problem is equivalent to finding the maximum directed cut in the auxiliary graph.

Example:

[image]

Comment: ...which effectively means this problem is NP-hard. I guess the slides I posted saying the "maximal...parallelism can easily be computed from this" are wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Ariel Not necessarily. The Maximum Directed Cut problem is NP-hard, but its subset may be not. Also, the problem you linked to is substantially different in that every task takes a predefined amount of time.

Comment: You're right, I mixed up the direction of the reduction so my conclusion is wrong. This reduction would allow me then to apply approximations known for max d-cut, I assume you'd share a tight solution for max parallelism if you had one.

Answer (score 1):

You should find `critical path length` in DAG. A critical path is a directed
path that has the maximum execution requirement among all other paths in DAG. `critical path length` in DAG with n node has n node. So `maximal parallelism` is `n`.

Critical path is `longest path` from root to leaf (in DAG) and for find it you can use **BFS** algorithm ([Breath First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).

**Example 1**

[image: BFS]

`BFS order` in this tree is `O(|V|+|E|)`. This is optimal solution for this problem.

**Edit: Find maximum degree of concurrency by BFS**

You can determine the maximum degree of concurrency by running the breadth-first search algorithm too:

- The algorithm starts from the root node  and proceeds towards the
  leafs level-wise.
- before inspecting nodes located on the next level it explores all of
  the nodes belonging to the **same level**.
- Count the number of nodes on each level and update a variable holding
  the maximum number of nodes per level.

**Example 2 (Step by step)**

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

[image: Step3]

[image: Step4]

So in this example maximum degree of concurrency is 4.

**Final Edit**

With the last explanations you gave, [Maximal independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set#Random-priority_parallel_algorithm) of tasks is what you are looking for. To solve this problem see [this article](http://ac.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss_12/netalg/lectures/chapter6.pdf).

Comment: I think your solution is incorrect. Consider this example: `start->[a1,a2, ..., a100, a101], a1->end, a2->end,..., a100->end, a101->b->c->end` - according to your solution, the max parallelism should be the length of `start->a101->b->c->end` which is 5, but clearly the max parallelism is 101 - all of a1,...,a101 can run concurrently.

Comment: @Ariel I added description for my solution and I made an example for it.

Comment: @Ariel I think solution is correct and is better than `user3290797` answer in this problem. Please see this again.

Comment: @user3290797 I think `BFS` is optimal solution for this problem. Please see my description and tell me if my solution is not right where I'm wrong.

Comment: see Edit 1 for illustration of a counterexample that shows why your approach is incorrect.

Comment: @Ariel I added final edit to my answer. Please see this.

Comment: Again incorrect: consider this graph: `a->b, a->c, b->d, c->d, d->e, e->f`
the max independent set size is 3, e.g. `b`, `c` and `e`, however clearly max parallelism is only 2.

Comment: `a->b, a->c, b->d, c->d, d->e, e->f`

Comment: @Ariel max independent set has 2 element. `e` is dependent to `c`.

Comment: An independent set only needs to have all member nodes be not adjacent to each other (i.e. have a direct edge). There's no constraints on indirect dependency. Therefore these problems are not equivalent, and solving max independent set does not solve max parallelism.

Comment: @Ariel In your problem, for find max independent set, you should not use your DAG directly. You need a new relation that shows if execution one node is dependent on execution of the another node, these two nodes are interconnected.

Comment: So basically you're suggesting a reduction to another NP-hard problem, like @user3290797 suggested for max d-cut. Unfortunately this doesn't help in getting an efficient solution for the problem.

Comment: @Ariel No. You need create new graph by [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) and find max independent set for this. This solution isn't NP-Hard in this issue. Please see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16823/maximum-degree-of-concurrency-in-task-dependency-graphs). I think it helps you.

Comment: Just adding an alternative that suited my scenario, `topological_sort` which produces the BFS sets in this answer. https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the algorithm, but my proposal would be the following:

1. Start from the origin node.
2. Select each connected edge. Current concurrency is the number of selected edges. Remember that.
3. Sort the selected nodes which are connected by the edges by the number of outgoing edges. Ignore all nodes, which have incoming edges which weren't yet selected.
4. Start going down the edge with the node with the most outgoing edges.
5. If not at end node: Repeat from 2)
6. Get the maximum of current concurrency for all iterations.

[Here](https://github.com/JulianWgs/max_para_dag) is an implementation in python using networkx. The document you have linked does something different. It calculates the number of concurrent tasks when the graph is executed with the attached timings to the nodes (1 for each node in that case). This is an easy tasks and probably the one the author of the document refers to. My algorithm however calculates the theoretical maximum and does not take the running time of each task into account.

Answer (score 0):

## Maximal Concurrency Heuristic:

#### Widest Generation in a Topologically Sorted DAG

Expanding upon Ali Soltani's work above in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825790/622276) that uses a breadthfirst search and gets the width of each generation.

### tl;dr

```py
import networkx as nx
gens = [sorted(generation) for generation in nx.topological_generations(DAG)]
gens
```

**Example Output:**

```
[[0], [1], [2, 5], [3, 4, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

```py
max([len(g) for g in gens])

3
```

### Code Example (Github + Colab)

- https://github.com/neozenith/notebook-network-maximum-parallelism/

[image: Open in Colab]

### Full Example

Creating a copy of the above code to here for posterity.

#### Step 1

Setup a random DAG of 10 nodes and other pieces needed for Google Colab.

```py
# !pip install networkx ipycytoscape -qq

import networkx as nx
import random
import ipycytoscape as cy
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

G=nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.5,directed=True)
DAG = nx.DiGraph([(u,v,{'weight':1}) for (u,v) in G.edges() if u<v])
```

#### Step 2 [Optional] - Visualise

```py
directed = cy.CytoscapeWidget()
directed.graph.add_graph_from_networkx(DAG, directed=True)
directed.set_layout(name='dagre')
directed
```

#### Step 3

```py
gens = [sorted(generation) for generation in nx.topological_generations(DAG)]
gens, max([len(g) for g in gens])
```

Comment: This will not necessarily find the maximum; but it is a decent heuristic. Sorting the generations in reverse order (i.e., distance from "sink" not "source") doesn't always give the same result, but can be useful as well.

Comment: @HansOlsson good point. I’ll update the wording from maximum to maximal for accuracy.